# Regular Expression match specific tag

Tags: c#, regex

I write a regular expression that is

```
<w:p.*>\[.*content.*\].*</w:p>
```

It is working fine. But sometime matches non require tag.

I've found a string from word processing like as

```
<w:p w:rsidR=‘00E52FD7’ w:rsidRDefault=‘00341592’ w:rsidP=‘000307E7’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Heading1’/><w:contextualSpacing w:val=‘0’/><w:jc w:val=‘center’/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:drawing><wp:inline distT=‘0’ distB=‘0’ distL=‘0’ distR=‘0’ wp14:anchorId=‘4F64B28D’ wp14:editId=‘6522B16C’><wp:extent cx=‘1358306’ cy=‘1343025’/><wp:effectExtent l=‘0’ t=‘0’ r=‘0’ b=‘0’/><wp:docPr id=‘2’ name=‘Picture 2’ descr=‘N:\HUMAN RESOURCES\Logos\Rancho-Logo-Type-Black.png’/><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a=‘http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main’ noChangeAspect=‘1’/></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic xmlns:a=‘http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main’><a:graphicData uri=‘http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture’><pic:pic xmlns:pic=‘http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture’><pic:nvPicPr><pic:cNvPr id=‘0’ name=‘Picture 1’ descr=‘N:\HUMAN RESOURCES\Logos\Rancho-Logo-Type-Black.png’/><pic:cNvPicPr><a:picLocks noChangeAspect=‘1’ noChangeArrowheads=‘1’/></pic:cNvPicPr></pic:nvPicPr><pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed=‘rId7’ cstate=‘print’><a:extLst><a:ext uri=‘{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}’><a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14=‘http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main’ val=‘0’/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:blip><a:srcRect/><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></pic:blipFill><pic:spPr bwMode=‘auto’><a:xfrm><a:off x=‘0’ y=‘0’/><a:ext cx=‘1374505’ cy=‘1359042’/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst=‘rect’><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom><a:noFill/><a:ln><a:noFill/></a:ln></pic:spPr></pic:pic></a:graphicData></a:graphic></wp:inline></w:drawing></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘00341592’ w:rsidRPr=‘00341592’ w:rsidRDefault=‘002F27D8’ w:rsidP=‘00341592’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Subtitle’/><w:contextualSpacing w:val=‘0’/><w:rPr><w:sz w:val=‘36’/><w:szCs w:val=‘36’/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space=‘preserve’>Job Description: </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR=‘00360E41’><w:t>Irrigation/</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidR=‘004A20D0’><w:t>Maintenance Worker</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘000307E7’ w:rsidRDefault=‘000307E7’ w:rsidP=‘000307E7’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Normal1’/></w:pPr><w:bookmarkStart w:id=‘0’ w:name=‘h.17ary2u5jp34’ w:colFirst=‘0’ w:colLast=‘0’/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id=‘0’/></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘00007B19’ w:rsidRDefault=‘00007B19’ w:rsidP=‘00341592’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Normal1’/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘00533338’ w:rsidRDefault=‘000307E7’ w:rsidP=‘00341592’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Normal1’/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space=‘preserve’>Rancho has reviewed the duties described within this job description to ensure that essential functions and basic duties are included.  It is not designed to cover or contain a comprehensive listing of activities, duties or responsibilities required of an incumbent.  An incumbent may be asked to perform other duties as required or assigned by their supervisor.  </w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘00533338’ w:rsidRDefault=‘00533338’ w:rsidP=‘00341592’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Normal1’/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘00710D42’ w:rsidRDefault=‘00710D42’ w:rsidP=‘00341592’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Normal1’/></w:pPr></w:p><w:p w:rsidR=‘004618DB’ w:rsidRDefault=‘004618DB’ w:rsidP=‘004618DB’><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val=‘Normal1’/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>[</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type=‘gramStart’/><w:r><w:t>content</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type=‘gramEnd’/><w:r><w:t>]</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

My requirement is selecting `<w:p>` tag which contains

> [content]

But this expression matches extra `<w:p>` tag which not contains my require text.

Any one can help me?

Comment: regex is not the recommended way to parse XML

Comment: I need to find specific word containing tag and replace by another. So, how can?

Comment: `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?s)<w:p\b[^>]*>.*?</w:p>").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).Where(z => z.Contains("[content]"))`.

Comment: Well, it is not quite precise, I assumed `[content]` is not likely to appear in `<w:p...>`. You have got the gist though. If you see a precise regex, you will most likely want to do it the right way using an XML parser. The regex will look like `(?s)<w:p\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<w:p\b).)*?\[content].*?</w:p>`

Comment: Thanks for your cordial help. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to use an XML parser if you have an XML file to deal with. If you have this short fragment only, and you need it to do a one-off task, you may use either of the two regex approaches.

*Extract all matches you want and check which one contains `[content]`, and only return that substring*:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"(?s)<w:p\b[^>]*>(.*?)</w:p>")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Where(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Contains("[content]"))
    .Select(z => z.Value);
```

Note that here, `(?s)<w:p\b[^>]*>(.*?)</w:p>` matches `<w:p`, then asserts there is no word char immediately to the right with a `\b` word boundary, then matches the rest of the element by consuming 0+ chars other than `>` and then `>`, then it captures any 0+ chars, as few as possible, into Group 1 (`x.Groups[1].Value`) and finally matches `</w:p>`. The `.Where(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Contains("[content]"))` condition only keeps those that contain `[content]` in the inner XML part of the `w:p` element.

*Use a more sophisticated regex with a tempered greedy token:*

```
(?s)<w:p\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<w:p\b).)*?\[content].*?</w:p>
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline option
- `<w:p` - a `<w:p` substring
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[^>]*` - 0+ chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>`
- `(?:(?!<w:p\b).)*?` - any char, 0+ times but as few as possible, that is not a starting point for `<w:p` followed with  a word boundary sequence
- `\[content]` - a `[content]` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `</w:p>` - a literal `</w:p>` substring

Comment: Thanks for your cordial help